# Is it normal for Helvetica Neue to appear squashed and pixelated on browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, fonts

Recently, I installed the font Helvetica Neue on my Windows machine and all of a sudden, websites that use Helvetica Neue are rendering weirdly on my browser (I'm using Google Chrome). What I'm not sure of is if it is right for the font Helvetica Neue to look squashed, badly condensed and pixelated?

Here's a screenshot of how the font appears on my screen on websites that use Helvetica Neue:

[image]

I took this screenshot on Graphics.SE. To prove that this really is Helvetica Neue from the Graphics.SE site, here's a screenshot of its CSS:

[image]

Now, this doesn't just happen on Graphics.SE, but on *every* webpages that uses Helvetica Neue. Is this really how the font should look? How should it look if everything was rendered correctly?

Comment: Where did you get the font file(s) from? When you view the font in "Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Fonts", what does it look like? My first impression is that the font file you installed only includes the Condensed version. See this page for the different styles: http://www.linotype.com/1266/neuehelvetica-family.html

Comment: I basically just copied the files from my old computer. I think it has the other versions of Neue because I can access those in Photoshop, but apparently, in my Control Panel\Fonts, they are not grouped together but in separate files. Could this be the problem?

Comment: what about other browsers?

Comment: On Firefox, it looks less condensed, but much bolded. It is very different from the way it looks on Chrome though.